# How to Configure SMTP on wordpress Cant Send Email

Tags: email, wp-mail, smtp

I am Currently working on a project in which my only problem is SENDING an email from site to Gmaill yahoo etc.

I want to configure the SMTP so I can make Independent Email Sending.

My problem is the company that I am working on. Is using a local Server which is just connected to the HOST. I cant Send Email using PHP mail or plugins from wordpress..

Is there anyway to send email in this CASE

Sorry for the Bad English Hope you Still Understands it

Comment: Have you tried an [SMTP mail plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the problem is. You certainly should be able to send email using PHP mail or plugins from wordpress.

Is it a security problem? Your password being rejected at authentication? Try using OAuth 2.0. https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/

Is it a firewall problem? Are all the SMTP ports blocked? Try sending with an HTTPS API like Gmail or Mandrill. https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-gmail-extension/