# How to send mail from Wordpress if one server hosts page and another email?

Tags: email

The website VPS has the domain name *name.com* and the mail server *mail.name.com*.

I successfully send and receive mail using *mail.name.com* using postfix and dovecot.

However, when I try to register a new user on my page, the new user receives no mail,
and consequently cannot register.
This made me install the plugin "WP Mail SMTP", with TLS and port 587, and *Authentication*
off. In addition to letting you use your own mail server, you can use this plugin with
Google, mailgun, and other services.

In the *From Email* field I use *name@mail.name.com*. When I try to send a test email, I
get the following message:

> Could not connect to the SMTP host.
>
> This means your web server was unable to connect to mail.name.com.
>
> Typically this error is returned for one of the following reasons:
>
> -SMTP settings are incorrect (wrong port, security setting, incorrect host).
>
> -Your web server is blocking the connection.
>
> -Your SMTP host is rejecting the connection.

In order to troubleshoot this problem, I need to understand the underlying mechanism, which
I do not.

**Do I have to open mail ports on name.com and use it as a relay? Or does the plugin automagically verify directly with mail.name.com?**

The latter makes more sense to me, as I
can also use Google and other third-party services. That also explains why I need to set up
SMTP authentication (SASL). But before I do anything, I would like a wiser person to confirm this suspicion or point me
in the right direction, as I know it will be a lot of hassle (or should I say sassle?).

**Do I have to set up SASSL on mail.name.com?**

Comment: try this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70716/sending-all-emails-using-smtp?rq=1 or this topic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177004/how-to-configure-smtp-on-wordpress-cant-send-email?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I read the posts and tried the function, but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do the job for you. those answer are working; follow the directions and/or use the suggested plugins.

Comment: Of course, Fernando. In fact, I am asking someone to verify whether or not I would need to set up SASSL or not. I am not asking anyone to do the work for me, that would not be any fun :)

Comment: your main question is in the title, but I never had to use it.